# "Cannot Open" error on making Jupyter Voila app using MyBinder

Tags: deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, computer-vision, image-classification, fast-ai

As given in the Fastai course, I tried making a notebook app based on image classification. After putting all the relevant files in the GitHub repository when I finally use Binder, even when Binder is successful in pushing the files and building the app, on clicking the link to the app I get an error:

```
Cannot Open
Could not find path: voila/render/path/to/dogs-app.ipynb
```

Can anyone help resolve this issue?

**Edit**:

Link to my repository: [My Repository](https://github.com/utkarsh1236/Dog-Breed-Classification-Using-Fastai)

Link to Fastai bear_voila repository: [Fastai Repository](https://github.com/fastai/bear_voila)

Link to Voila docs: [Docs](https://voila.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploy.html#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20mybinder.org%20and%20enter%20the%20URL%20of,has%20been%20new%20changes%20since%20the%20last%20build%29.)

Comment: Chances are you just aren't using the correct URL or trying to access the Voila page via the way compatible with MyBinder. It can be tricky when first using it. However, you aren't sharing the repo you are trying to make work here and so it's hard to tell you what to do. There's a [Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/) with a 'Binder help' category that this type of question would be better suited for in the future. Exchange of info to work out the issue is encouraged. At this point if you provide more information here, it may be possible to get it working.

Comment: I'd also suggest your title isn't exactly clear. You are making a Jupyter Voila app, I believe using MyBinder. And your issue is you cannot open the app? Plus, if you are using a reference, you should provide the reference. Does this Fastai course have a page you can point at?

Comment: Hi @Wayne ! thanks for your response. I have made the required edits as per your suggestions :)

Comment: The fact you don't provide the link you are trying to use to launch into your Voila app makes me think you aren't understanding how to use things with MyBinder. Have you looked at any examples? I have several under 'Direct Links' at https://github.com/fomightez/communication_voila#direct-links.  You may want to examine the links closely. Or search on the Discourse site where I work out helping others get the URLs right for Voila. Also look closely at the launch URL for the bear_voila repository.

Comment: When I try to run your code in Voila, it isn't liking the second cell that is `learn_inf = load_learner(Path()/'export.pkl')` in your `dogs-app.ipynb`. You can just try running the first two cells in that in the notebook [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/utkarsh1236/Dog-Breed-Classification-Using-Fastai/HEAD) and see there's an error in that second cell. Voila won't work until it gets no errors.

Comment: Also, so you know. You can launch the JupyterLab for your project at https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/utkarsh1236/Dog-Breed-Classification-Using-Fastai/HEAD and then open your `dogs-app.ipynb` notebook by double clicking it. To open Voila from the notebook, you then click on the Voila symbol in the upper middle of the notebook pane. The yellow squiggle with with a green line below it. Click on that. That's how you develop in Voila using MyBinder & JupyterLab. Once Voila works that way, you can use the URL information I pointed you are above to launch directly into the Voila mode.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Wayne :) I could finally get my web app up and running. I fixed that error in the second cell by changing the requirements.txt file as per the versions of libraries used in my export.pkl file.